# Passing value with Loop from Javascript to Page variable

Tags: php

I am have a Java script with  Document element .load  as a  event
and I am  loading the File .php at a Interval of some seconds (Ex 30 sec )

Objective   I  have a Page variable passed to a php page in Javascript as show 
   .load('sample.php?page=1'
and I would like to  change the Page number and assign continues changing number values like count (say 5 number )

```
.load('sample.php?page=1' 
.load('sample.php?page=2' 
.load('sample.php?page=3' 
.load('sample.php?page=4' 
.load('sample.php?page=5'
```

and  keep looping continuously until stop event 
a Help for the same highly appreciated

in the Code below is the Java script with  assigned page values a
page=1
I want to pass number from 1 to n Number continuously in loop and stop with Click event

Loading   page number continuously in loop

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        enter code here
        $(document).ready(function(){
          refreshTable();

        });
     function refreshTable(){
            $('.autodata').load('datafetch_2.php?page=1', function(){
               setTimeout(refreshTable,30000);
            });
        }

    </script>
```

No Errors to Display 
as mentioned above stop the Page count in Click event

Answer (score 0):

Put the page number in a variable, increment it each time, and append that to the URL.

```
let pageNum = 0;
function refreshTable(){
    pageNum++;
    if (pageNum > <?php echo $lastPage; ?>) {
        pageNum = 1;
    }
    $('.autodata').load('datafetch_2.php?page=' + pageNum, function(){
       setTimeout(refreshTable,30000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank for the reply  Barmar  
 I could Pass the value for 0  to   ++  the pages have displayed accordingly  But  the same has not stopped as the Page ended  I have 12 Page   from pagination count  logic 

I would like to  assign the Number  accumulated from   Pagination Page   Different page  example : Pagination.php 
and loop count the pages available   and  as I end  I again would like to  continue from One

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding you. Are you asking how to make it stop or go back to the beginning when it gets to the last page?

Comment: It would be easier if you used an AJAX call that returns JSON. The JSON can include a flag that says whether it's the last page.

Comment: the below   assumption is  correct I'm having trouble understanding you. Are you asking how to make it stop or go back to the beginning when it gets to the last page=1  
Let me  explain the requirement  
I have Excel Data which I have  extracted the  rows and Grouped   10  rows and  made a Pagination for the same and I get 12 pages 
I want to  loop  

now as I have pages  I would like to pass the page number  1,2 3, in to Page=Var 
as the  pages number are in Different  .php file I would like get the the same in  Javascript in Loading Page and  with interval I want to Display them

Comment: Dear Barmer

Below is the  code I am trying  the same 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();  });    
 function refreshTable(){
       pagenum= 0;
  while (pagenum <= "<?php echo $page1 ?>";) {
        $('.autodata').load('datafetch_2.php?page=' + pagenum, function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTable,30000);
        } 
}  pagenum++; );
  }
</script>

Comment: It makes no sense to call `.load()` in a loop. They'll all start immediately, overwriting what each one does.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to cycle the page number back to 1. This uses a variable `$maxPage` that's set by PHP when the page is first opened, so if the number pages on the server changes it won't get the update.

Comment: Dear Barmar 
Gr8 I could able to Hardcode the last page value  as  per answer
and  the logic worked as the  Page Kept looping and completes the Cycle  
Now I am  trying to  get the  Page Count  Number extracted in another page 
Please guide how to fetch the page values collected to the lastpage variable
below is the  code for pagination technique applied 
$tot=$i++;
$cnt= $tot/5;
$cnt=Ceil($cnt);
for ($b = 1;$b <= $cnt; $b++){ ?> <a href="datafetch_2.php?page=<?php echo $b;  ?> " style="text-decoration:none">    <?php  echo $b."" ; ?> </a>  <?php ?>